# Django add 1 to pages.current before printing it (django-endless-pagination)

Tags: django, html, css, django-endless-pagination

I have a variable, pages.current.  I want to display this variable + 1 on a web page.  (i.e. if pages.current is 1, I want it to show 2; etc).

My current code:

```
<p>Page {{ pages.current|add:"1" }} </p>.
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be working (that code simply displays pages.current's value, without the +1) and I don't understand why.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you define "not working"? Is it throwing an error? Not appearing? Appearing but without 1 added?

Comment: Also: have you tried changing it to `{{ pages.current|add:"1" }}` as per the [example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#add)?

Comment: I'm sorry.  By "not working" I mean that {{ pages.current|add:1 }} displays the pages.current value, but not the incremented value.  Yes I tried it with add:"1" as well-

Comment: Just to confirm that the problem isn't elsewhere, have you tried putting something like `nonincremented: {{ pages.current }} incremented: {{ pages.current|add:"1" }}` into your template? That would make it 100% clear that the `add` filter isn't working.

Comment: @DavidRobinson was just about to suggest the same. OP's issue seems a little unlikely.

Comment: I tried this code: Page {{ pages.current|add:"1" }} nonincremented: {{ pages.current }} .  Every time they display the same number:  Page 1 nonincremented 1, Page 2 nonincremented 2, etc

Comment: I've tried to replicate this but can't. When I use a template `nonincremented: {{ testvar }} incremented: {{ testvar|add:"1" }}`, and give it the dictionary `{"testvar": "1"}`, the resulting page shows `nonincremented: 1 incremented: 2`.

Comment: Just to start getting desperate, try adding a new variable `testvar` to the dictionary, whose value is 1. (The only thing I can think of is that it has something to do with the kind of variable that `pages.current` is). If that also doesn't work, we'll have to go into the `add` tag itself.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  There must be something going on with the pages.current variable I've gotten from django-endless-pagination.  Will look into it now-

Comment: Don't forget to let us know what it is!